# Higher dimensional analogue of an arc of a circle

Tags: geometry, reference-request, terminology

What is the higher dimensional analogue for the arc of a circle?

I'd like to work with the set of all points lying within a certain distance of a given point on an n-sphere, and I'd like to describe these sets by the (generalised) solid angles which they subtend.

Comment: A spherical wedge, or a spherical cap?

Comment: Or hyperspherical, as the case may be. It's easy to denote it as an intersection of a ball and a sphere.

Comment: @J.M. Make that an answer, would you please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By request:

It seems you want either the [spherical cap](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html) or the [spherical wedge](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalWedge.html), or hyperspherical versions thereof.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Thanks also to anon.